# Ayuda con lógica de suma de filas individual con name="" javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo una tabla que agrego filas de forma dinámica y que tengo que hacer la suma por filas, estoy usando `name` por que por `id` no me permite mostrar mas de un id.

Código de suma por filas y la suma total de columna.

```
function totalizar() {
t_cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
t_precio = document.getElementsByName("precio_unidad[]");
// t_fila =document.getElementsByName("total_fila[]");
t_fila = []

for(var x = 0; x < t_precio.length; x++){
    t_fila[x] = t_cantidad[x].value * t_precio[x].value;   
}

t_suma = 0
for (var i = 0; i < t_fila.length; i++) {
    t_suma += t_fila[i]
}
console.log(t_suma)}
```

si lo hago de esa forma obtengo estos resultados.

[image: Tabla con la suma total de la columna]

[image: y eso es la suma mostrada por consola]

en lo que necesito ayuda es como mostrar en cada fila el valor de la multiplicación entre cantidad y precio y luego el subtotal para generar el resto como muestro en la imagen.

```
<tbody class="t-equipos-body" id="t-equipos-add">
                                    @php ($cant = 1)
                                    {{-- @foreach ($referencia as $item) --}}
                                    <tr  class="tr_nuevo_equipo" id="Proforma_{{$cant}}">
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                            <input step="0" min="0" value="0" name="cantidad[]" type="number" id="valor-cantidad" onkeyup="totalizar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                            <textarea placeholder="... ..."  name="descripcion[]">d</textarea>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                            <input step="0" value="0" min="0" name="precio_unidad[]" type="number" id="valor-precio" onkeyup="totalizar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="total_fila[]" onkeyup="totalizar()" readonly>
                                            <span id="totales-filas"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle"><i class="fas fa-trash" onclick="eliminar_linea('Proforma_{{$cant}}')"></i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                     @php ($cant++)
                                    {{-- @endforeach  --}}
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes incluir el html de la tabla?

Comment: @Jemonge, listo amigo ya subi el html de la tabla

Comment: Estas usando algún framework o algo?, es que hay cosas en las que me quedo con dudas... por ejemplo el formato extraño de las etiquetas name, parece un array como lo pones, y al final el metodo getElementsByName si te trae un arreglo, pero porque la función eso es lo que retorna, sin embargo ten en cuenta que lo de poner los corchetes no es necesario... ¿A lo mejor lo hiciste así para guiarte mejor?, otra cosa que puedo ver es que en tu código es que no se donde declaras la variable t_suma como var o let si lo haces fuera de la función bien, pero si no, deberias considerar ponerle var o let.

Comment: El formato que usas de php, seguramente sea nuevo o talvez tenga que ver con otras cosas que no vienen al caso... intentaste usar la forma clasica de usar php para que se ejecute el forEach?, intentalo a ver que pasa, lo otro es que las llaves que usas {{$valor}}, me recuerdan a angular... estas usando angular?, o es acaso una nueva forma que no conocía de php para usar las variables...?, según tengo entendido eso de las llaves dobles es de angular y otros frameworks y en caso de angular solo te permite usar variables de typescritpt no de php.

Comment: es framework laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando tu código html, lo primero que noto es que estás definiendo IDs dentro del foreach. Eso es incorrecto porque el código te generará múltiples IDs con el mismo nombre, por eso no se te muestra. En este caso lo mejor es usar las clases.

Ahora, el proceso para calcular los totales no es muy complejo. Lo que debes hacer es recorrer cada una de las filas de la tabla e ir calculando el monto para incluir el dato en esa misma fila. Tu planteamiento está bien, pero podría ser más sencillo.

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo funcional:

```js
function totalizar() {
    const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("tr_nuevo_equipo");
    let total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

      const cantidad = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor-cantidad')[0].value;
      const precio = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor-precio')[0].value;
      const total_fila = cantidad * precio;

      rows[i].getElementsByClassName('totales-filas')[0].value = total_fila;
      total += total_fila
    }

    document.getElementById("total").innerText = total;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tbody class="t-equipos-body" id="t-equipos-add">

  <tr  class="tr_nuevo_equipo" id="Proforma_1">
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input step="0" min="0" value="10" name="cantidad[]" type="number" class="valor-cantidad" onkeyup="totalizar()">
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <textarea placeholder="... ..."  name="descripcion[]">d</textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input step="0" value="1" min="0" name="precio_unidad[]" type="number" class="valor-precio" onkeyup="totalizar()">
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input type="number" name="total_fila[]" class="totales-filas" value="10" readonly>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle"><i class="fas fa-trash" onclick="eliminar_linea('Proforma_1')"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="tr_nuevo_equipo" id="Proforma_2">
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input step="0" min="0" value="5" name="cantidad[]" type="number" class="valor-cantidad" onkeyup="totalizar()">
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <textarea placeholder="... ..."  name="descripcion[]">d</textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input step="0" value="100" min="0" name="precio_unidad[]" type="number" class="valor-precio" onkeyup="totalizar()">
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle">
      <input type="number" name="total_fila[]" class="totales-filas" value="500" readonly>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle"><i class="fas fa-trash" onclick="eliminar_linea('Proforma_2')"></i></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
  TOTAL: <span id="total">510</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Buen planteamiento, pero la idea no era que las filas mostradas fueran dinamicas dependiendo de la variable $referencia de php?, faltaría lo de que fuera dinamico según la variable de php, que seguro trae datos de una BD...

Comment: @Riven no, ese foreach esta comentado no se utilizara por ahora.

Comment: Pero funciona el foreach no?, pues si lo descomentas...

Comment: @Jemonge, amigo tu código si me ayuda al problema de la suma de fila y columna, me habia generado otro problema por que la clase "tr_nuevo_equipo" la estaba usando para tomar y generar el siguiente TR, solo agregue otra clase y con eso ya se soluciono, MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: Perfecto @DuvalAlcivarDemera, me alegro que te haya funcionado.